# Two finite field of same order is isomorphic. Simplest way to prove it.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to prove that two finite field of same order is isomorphic.

I have thought something.

My attempt :  If $f$  be a field of order $p ^m $ then $(f,+)$ is $z_p × z_p × .......z_p$.

$(f , .) $ is $z_{p^m - 1}$.

Am I right? Can anyone please check ? If I am right can you please tell how to conclude then?

If I am wrong can you please tell me a trivial way of seeing it. I am a first reader of field theory.

Comment: Having isomorphic additive and isomorphic multiplicative groups is not sufficient in and of itself to prove isomorphism. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74362/non-isomorphic-finite-rings-with-isomorphic-additive-and-multiplicative-structur

Comment: The easiest way to prove this is to show that a field of order $p^n$ is the splitting field, over $\mathbb{F}_p$, of $x^{p^n}-x$.

Comment: How much I need to read understand splitting field?

Comment: That seems like a strange question. The answer is “enough”. In absolute terms, it depends on how much you already know. Trying to construct an isomorphism when you don’t know much about fields and field extensions, and you don’t know much about what the fields look like, is going to take at least as much effort as to learn enough basic field theory to do it the easy way. Your path is going to be pretty hard, because you haven’t even begun to connect the additive and multiplicative structures.

Comment: Btw in your link the question is different...multiplicative structure is not assumed group there..

Comment: which means it’s more general. (Also, because I am taking into account the $0$). Of course, the example doesn’t involve fields (because finite fields of the same size *are* isomorphic). But the point is that you cannot just go from “additive groups are isomorphic and multiplicative groups are isomorphic” to “fields are isomorphic”. You don’t know whether the two isomorphisms are the same or compatible.